# Rounding a math calculation up, without math.ceil()?

Tags: python, math, missing-features

I'm working on a system which doesn't have the `math` module available. All "Math" functions installed (`math.ceil()`, `math.round()`, etc all produce errors).

I have even tried using `import math` which yields:

```
<type 'ImportError'>
__import__ not found
```

Current issue that is stumping me: How can I make a math calculation round up to a whole number without `math.ceil`?

Comment: check if `x - int(x)` is greater than 0? So something like `int(x) + (1 if x - int(x) > 0 else 0)`

Comment: How about `int(x//1) + 1` ?

Comment: @D.LaRocque that doesn't work if `x` is already an integer.

Comment: True, use `x if isinstance(x, int) else int(x//1) + 1` or use the answer from @Rory Daulton

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If `x` is a float number that you want to round up to an integer, and you want an integer type result, you could use

```
rounded_up_x = int(-(-x // 1))
```

This works because integer division by one rounds down, but using the negative sign before and after doing the division rounds the opposite direction. The `int` here converts the float result to an integer. Remove that `int` if you want a floating point value that equals an integer, which is what some programming languages do.

Hat-tip to @D.LaRocque for pointing out that Python's `ceil()` function returns an integer type.

Comment: It looks like `math.ceil` returns `int` everytime, so we can use `int(- (-x // 1))` to avoid negative zeros.

Comment: @D.LaRocque: Many thanks, I have corrected my answer. I guess I was confused by C or Pascal, which I believe return an integer but in floating-point type.

Comment: oh, and what I didn't realize until the conversation about integer vs float... one of my numbers in the calculation was stored as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

The ceiling of `x` is the smallest integer greater than or equal to `x`. So just add 1 if the decimal part of `x` is non-zero.

One simply way would be:

```
def myCeil(x):
    return int(x) + int((x>0) and (x - int(x)) > 0)
```

Examples:

```
print([myCeil(i) for i in [myCeil(i) for i in [-2, -1.1, -0.0, 0, 1, 1.2, 3]])
#[-2, -1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it. I think this should work in most versions of python.

```
def ceil(n):
    q, r = divmod(n, 1)
    return int(q) + bool(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

in Python 3, we have [`object.__ceil__()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ceil__) that is even called by `math.ceil` internally,

```py
num = 12.4 / 3.3
print(num)
3.757575757575758
num.__ceil__()
4
```

Or one can always negate the result of a negated number's floor division (and create a new int object unless a float would do),

```
int(-(-12.4 // 3.3))
4
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy and intuitive way to do it if x isn't a negative number:

```
rounded = round(x)
if rounded < x:
    rounded_up_x = rounded + 1
else:
    rounded_up_x = rounded
```

Answer (score -1):

it can be simply done by the following code (this is how I always do). No math library needed

y = x if x==x//1 else round(x+0.5)

Comment: This does not work for `0`, or whole numbers in general. `round(3+0.5) = 4` when the correct result should be `3`

Comment: @pault: In my Python 3.7.3 it does work for zero and any even integer value but not for any odd integer value. This is due to `round`'s banker's rounding, also called symmetric rounding--it rounds to the nearest *even* integer if the fractional part is 0.5.

Comment: It may not work in python 2.7.x, but will work in python 3.x.x

Comment: @KrishnaRao it does not work for odd numbers in python 3.6.5 or 2.7

Comment: @pault Right you are .. I have checked it now .. this is the old method I used in some of my previous tools ... but in python Rory 's code is good . Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score -4):

welcome to Stack.

As far as I've implemented in my codes, you don't need to `import math` to use `round()`.

Because, `round()` is a standalone function in python and not an extension of math package.

So, I suggest you go on and simply use `round()` instead of `math.round()` and you'll be fine.

Refer this [doc](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/round) to find out more about how to use `round()` function.

Comment: What about `ceil`? `round()` doesn't round up

Comment: `round()` does not round *up*, which is what the questioner wants.